# How can I use Facebook share button function on a custom button in MVC

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I want to use custom icon button on a facebook share code to share a link.

```
<script>
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.1';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-share-button fb-Button" data-href="http://www.oppa.ge/piggybank/1002102" data-layout="button" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true" style="margin-right:20px; float:right">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oppa.ge%2Fpiggybank%2F1002102&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" style="height:45px;">Share</a>
</div>
```

Update: So I tried FB.ui and I get an error in console So I tried FB ui and I get a problem with script
 " piggybank?isFullScreen=True:821 Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined at HTMLDivElement.document.getElementById.onclick "

```
<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function () { FB.ui({ method: 'share', display: 'popup', href: 'oppa.ge/piggybank/1002102';, }, function (response) { }); } </script>
```

Comment: So what isn't working?

Comment: you´re not allowed to do that with the facebook plugins...you can create your own custom share button though with FB.ui share or sharer.php.